# How to add Listener or double clicks element in DefaultListModel to open a new Jframe?

Tags: java

```
dlm = new DefaultListModel();
jl = new JList(dlm);
dlm.addElement("adfsdf");
```

I want to double clicks "adfsdf" then open a new JFrame,how to handle?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `MouseListener` to your `JList` which will check it's a double-click event, and that this double-clicks occurs over a list item. Then, in your mouse listener, you'll open the `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (haven't tested, but see the point) :

```
JList list = new JList(dataModel);
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            if ((String)list.getSelectedValue()).equals("adfsdf") {
              // do stuff
            }
         }
    }
};
list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ListAction](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) class allows you to add an Action to a list list you do for a JButton. The Action will be invoked on a mouse double click or when using Enter from the key board.